# Need to get an a sliding div to stay in the same place on page (JSFiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this is a solved problem, but I'm having difficulty getting this to work so I need some help.

I have the following setup: http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/3656/

The issue is, users will scroll past that slider. I need the slider to stay in the same place on the page.

I've tried using the classes approach (have a class called sticky with position: fixed;) but it didn't work for me unfortunately.

Any help would be appreciated.

JS from JSFiddle:

```
$(function () {
$("#slideout").click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass("popped")){
        $(this).animate({left:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 200}).removeClass("popped");
        } else {
        $(this).animate({left: "20px" }, {queue: false, duration: 200}).addClass("popped")
    }
});
$("#slideout").delay(500).animate({left: "20px" }, {queue: true, duration: 200}).addClass("popped");
});
```

CSS from JSFiddle:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#slideout {
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 45%;
  left: -280px;
  padding-right: 20px
}

#clickme {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #ff0000;
}

#slidecontent {
  float: right;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current position is set to `absolute` when it should be `fixed.`

You tried this?

```
#slideout {position:fixed;}
```

and it works fine for me here: **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/3672/)**

Comment: I was just doing the same thing and it works for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/releaf/zp9fes9e/

Comment: oh awesome, thanks so much - can't believe I missed that fix, appreciate your help mate!

Comment: Np! Just click the checkmark if everything is working for you now. Good luck!